# Add a custom markup to the title

Tags: 8, blocks

I created a custom block plugin to allow users to easily customize various elements of the block using configuration options in panels.

```
public function build(){
    return array(
        '#type' => 'markup',
        '#title' => '<h2 style="color:red;">Test</h2>',
        '#markup' => '<div class=' . $this->configuration['my_plugins_style'] . '>' . $this->configuration['my_plugins_string'] . '</div>',
    );
}
```

However I would like to customize elements of the title of the block as well. The title is automatically encased in between h2 tags and I'd rather the user choose what type of tag to encase the title. I attempted adding the markup within the '#title' options but that just renders all the markup as text.

Comment: Are you asking how to set the block title?

Comment: You should create a custom template for the block that will display the header with customizable tags

Comment: I know how to set the block title. I was able to accomplish this using the code above. I want the ability to change the html tags that the header is encapsulated in. I understand that I can create unique templates for each individual block but is there no way to customize the title using this block plugin? I'm able to customize everything else. Is title the only thing Drupal doesn't allow me to customize within the plugin?